# sql join with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've a table EMPLOYEE which has columns like these

`EmpId FName LName`

I have another table ADDRESS which has columns like these

```
EmpId AddressType Address Phone Email
```

AddressType column has 2 possible types, Residential and Official and an Emp can have both types of address. 
I need a query which will join these 2 tables using EmpId. 
It also needs to fetch one address which has phone not null. 
If both addresses has phone, then fetch any one, if none has phone, still fetch any one.
 Please help.

Comment: Please, explain your question further. Kindly, show some sample data. Also, show us what have you done already to solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to first decide which `Address` would be best for the `Employee`, based on your `Phone`-rule. After the prefered Address has been found, indicated by `PhonePreference = 1`, you can `JOIN` the correct `Address` on the `Employee`.

```
WITH AddressCTE AS (
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY EmpId 
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN Phone IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, Phone
    ) PhonePreference
    FROM Address
)

SELECT *
FROM Employee E
JOIN AddressCTE A ON E.EmpId = A.EmpId AND A.PhonePreference = 1
```